# __attribute__ and VisualC++

Tags: visual-c++, attributes

Hi I am trying to write a routine in VC ++ was originally compiled in GCC. When I make the following definition:

```
    typedef float v4sf __attribute__ (vector_size(16));
```

The compiler throws me the following error:

```
    C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '__attribute__'
```

As I can replace this line?

Thank you!

Comment: Just remove it, MSVC++ figures this out automatically.  VS2012 or higher required.

Comment: Or #define it away: `#define __attribute__(X)`